# Connecting JQGRID with MYSQL & ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, json, jqgrid

Im Currently Stack on how to display all the data of my database im new in using JQGRID and i dont know  why is  my data dont display when i deployed it on web using localhost

getdata.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


public partial class getdata : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public struct s_GridResult
    {
        public int page;
        public int total;
        public int record;
        public s_RowData[] rows;

    }
    public struct s_RowData
    {
        public int id;
        public string[] cell;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static s_GridResult GetDataTable(string _search, string nd, int rows, int page,
 string sidx, string sord)
    {

        int startindex = (page - 1);
        int endindex = page;
        string sql = "SELECT ItemCode,PartNumber FROM tblitemcodefromqne";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlConnection conn = new 
MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        s_GridResult result = new s_GridResult();
        List<s_RowData> rowsadded = new List<s_RowData>();
        int idx = 1;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            s_RowData newrow = new s_RowData();
            newrow.id = idx++;
            newrow.cell = new string[2];  //total number of columns  
            newrow.cell[0] = row[0].ToString();
            newrow.cell[1] = row[1].ToString();
            rowsadded.Add(newrow);
        }
        result.rows = rowsadded.ToArray();
        result.page = page;
        result.total = dt.Rows.Count;
        result.record = rowsadded.Count;
        return result;
    }


}
```

getdata.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1
/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="JQGridReq/jquery-
ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
     <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="JQGridReq/ui.jqgrid.css" />
     <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="Themes/style.css" />


     <script type="text/javascript" src="JQGridReq/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="JQGridReq/jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="JQGridReq/jquery-ui-1.9.4.custom.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="JQGridReq/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="JQGridReq/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>




      <script type="text/javascript" >
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $.extend($.jgrid.defaults,
                  { datatype: 'json' },
                  { ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json",
                      success: function (data, textStatus) {
                          if (textStatus == "success") {
                              var thegrid = $("#Grid1")[0];
                              thegrid.addJSONData(data.d);
                              thegrid.grid.hDiv.loading = false;
                              switch (thegrid.p.loadui) {
                                  case "disable":
                                      break;
                                  case "enable":
                                      $("#load_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                      break;
                                  case "block":
                                      $("#lui_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                      $("#load_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
                                      break;
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }




                  });


              jQuery("#Grid1").jqGrid({
                  url: 'getdata.aspx/GetDataTable',
                  datatype: 'json',
                  mtype: 'POST',
                  colNames: ['Item Code', 'Part Number'],
                  colModel: [{ name: 'ItemCode', index: 'ItemCode', width: 200 },
                   { name: 'PartNumber', index: 'PartNumber', width: 300}],
                  pager: '#pager', sortname: 'ItemCode',
                  viewrecoreds: true,
                  imgpath: 'JQGridReq/images',
                  serializeGridData: function (data) {
                      return $.toJSON(data);
                  }


              });
          });






     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table id="Grid1" class="scroll" align="center" width="100%"></table>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;">






    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions like ´Please help me now!´ won´t help in your advantage here on stack overflow. Read the FAQ and use punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer by my self here's what i did to implement JQGrid on ASP.net and MySQL database.

ItemCode.ashx

```
public struct JQGridResults
    {
        public int page;
        public int total;
        public int records;
        public JQGridRow[] rows;
    }



public struct JQGridRow
    {

        public string ItemCode;
        public string PartNumber;
        public string ItemDescriptionShort;
        public string ItemDescriptionLong;
        public string ProductCode;
        public string GroupCode;
        public string BusinessUnit;
        public string[] cell;
    }
    [Serializable]

public class User
    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescriptionShort { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescriptionLong { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string GroupCode { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemCode : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;

            string _search = request["_search"];
            string numberOfRows = request["rows"];
            string pageIndex = request["page"];
            string sortColumnName = request["sidx"];
            string sortOrderBy = request["sord"];


            int totalRecords;
            Collection <User> users = GetUsers(numberOfRows, pageIndex, sortColumnName,sortOrderBy, out totalRecords);
            string output = BuildJQGridResults(users, Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows),Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex), Convert.ToInt32(totalRecords));
            response.Write(output);
        }
        private string BuildJQGridResults(Collection <User> users, int numberOfRows, int pageIndex, int totalRecords)
        {

            JQGridResults result = new JQGridResults();
            List<JQGridRow> rows = new List<JQGridRow>();
            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                JQGridRow row = new JQGridRow();
                row.ItemCode = user.ItemCode;
                row.PartNumber = user.PartNumber;
                row.ItemDescriptionShort = user.ItemDescriptionShort;
                row.ItemDescriptionLong = user.ItemDescriptionLong;
                row.ProductCode = user.ProductCode;
                row.GroupCode = user.GroupCode;
                row.BusinessUnit = user.BusinessUnit;

                rows.Add(row);
            }
            result.rows = rows.ToArray();
            result.page = pageIndex;
            result.total = (totalRecords + numberOfRows - 1) / 8;
            result.records = totalRecords;
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue, RecursionLimit = 100 };
            //return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
            return serializer.Serialize(result);
        }


        private Collection<User> GetUsers(string numberOfRows, string pageIndex, string sortColumnName, string sortOrderBy, out int totalRecords)
        {
            Collection<User> users = new Collection<User>();
            MySqlConnection conn = Functions.GetConnection();
            string sql;
            sql = "SELECT *  FROM swans.tblsomain,tblligerstatus;";


            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader data1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            string connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;database=swans;uid=root;password=''";

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "select ItemCode,PartNumber,ItemDescriptionShort,ItemDescriptionLong,ProductCode,GroupCode,BusinessUnit from tblitemcodefromqne;";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    MySqlParameter paramPageIndex = new MySqlParameter("@PageIndex",MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    paramPageIndex.Value = Convert.ToInt32(pageIndex);
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramPageIndex);

                    MySqlParameter paramColumnName = new MySqlParameter("@SortColumnName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    paramColumnName.Value = sortColumnName;
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramColumnName);

                    MySqlParameter paramSortorderBy = new MySqlParameter("@SortOrderBy", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 4);
                    paramSortorderBy.Value = sortOrderBy;
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramSortorderBy);

                    MySqlParameter paramNumberOfRows = new MySqlParameter("@NumberOfRows", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    paramNumberOfRows.Value = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfRows);
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramNumberOfRows);

                    MySqlParameter paramTotalRecords = new MySqlParameter("@TotalRecords",MySqlDbType.Int32);
                    totalRecords = 0;
                    paramTotalRecords.Value = totalRecords;
                    paramTotalRecords.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(paramTotalRecords);


                    connection.Open();

                    using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        User user;
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            user = new User();
                            user.ItemCode = Convert.ToString(dataReader["ItemCode"]);
                            user.PartNumber = Convert.ToString(dataReader["PartNumber"]);
                            user.ItemDescriptionShort = Convert.ToString(dataReader["ItemDescriptionShort"]);
                            user.ItemDescriptionLong =Convert.ToString(dataReader["ItemDescriptionLong"]);
                            user.ProductCode = Convert.ToString(dataReader["ProductCode"]);
                            user.GroupCode = Convert.ToString(dataReader["GroupCode"]);
                            user.BusinessUnit = Convert.ToString(dataReader["BusinessUnit"]);
                            users.Add(user);
                        }
                    }
                    totalRecords = users.Count;

                }

                return users;
            }

        }



        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

ItemCode.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function () {
            $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ItemCode.ashx',
                datatype: "json",
                width: 1245,
                height: 450,
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records"
                },

                colNames: ['Item Code', 'Part Number', 'Short Description', 'Long Description', 'Product Code', 'Group Code', 'Business Unit'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'ItemCode', index: 'ItemCode', width: 60, editable:true, sorttype: 'string' },
                    { name: 'PartNumber', index:'PartNumber', width: 50  },
                    { name: 'ItemDescriptionShort',index:'ItemDescriptionShort', width: 260 },
                    { name: 'ItemDescriptionLong',index:'ItemDescriptionLong', width: 260  },
                    { name: 'ProductCode',index:'ProductCode', width: 50 },
                    { name: 'GroupCode',index:'GroupCode', width: 50 },
                    { name: 'BusinessUnit',index:'BusinessUnit', width: 50 },



                ],



                cmTemplate: { title: false },
                rowNum: 20,
                mtype: 'GET',
                loadonce: true,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#UsersGridPager',
                sortname: 'ItemCode',
                multiSort: true,
                gridview: true,
                viewrecords: true,

                sortorder: 'asc',
                caption: "Item Code Summary"


            });

            jQuery("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager',
            { del: false, add: false, edit: false, search: false });
            jQuery("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });



        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="UsersForm" runat="server">
<table id="UsersGrid" ></table>
 <div id="UsersGridPager"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The field names of the database table should match with the name in the colmodel which is in the javascript.

The java script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

         $(function() {
         var grid = jQuery("#myGrid");
         grid.jqGrid({
         url: "http://localhost:50530/jqGridHandler.ashx",
         mtype:'GET',
         datatype: "json",
         height: 200,
         hidegrid: false,//hides the arrow button at the top right corner for collapsing the jqGrid
         rowNum: 10,
         rowList: [10, 20, 30],
         viewrecords: true,
         caption: "Employees",
         pager: "#pager",
         colNames: ['FirstName', 'SecondName', 'DOB', 'EmailID','UserName'],
         colModel: [
             { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 100, align: "center" },
             { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 100, align: "left" },
             { name: 'DOB', index: 'DOB', width: 100, align: "center", formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm-d-Y' }, datefmt: 'm-d-Y' },
             { name: 'Email', index: 'EmailID', width: 120, align: "right"},
             { name: 'Username', index: 'Username', width: 100 }
                   ]
     });
});

</script>
```

the web component

```
<table id="myGrid"> </table>
```

the code behind (jqGridHandler.ashx)

```
 public class jqGridHandler : IHttpHandler
     {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        MyFirstService.Service1Client client = new MyFirstService.Service1Client();
        context.Response.Write(client.GetJsonUsers());
    }

    private DataSet GetUsersFromDB()
    {
        AccessDataBase reader = new AccessDataBase();
        string selectquery = "SELECT * FROM Registration";
        return reader.readDB(selectquery);
    }

    public string GetJsonUsers()
    {
        return GetJson(GetUsersFromDB());
    }


    private string GetJson(DataSet dt)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows =
          new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
        foreach (DataTable dtt in dt.Tables)
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dtt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }

        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

AccessDB.cs

```
 public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
        public AccessDataBase()
        {
            Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NewDB;Integrated Security=True");

        }

        public DataSet readDB(string selectquery)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectquery);
            using (Connection)
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = Connection;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        return ds;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and add

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

and don forget to add the js and css files in the master page.

```
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Scripts/JQGrid/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Scripts/JQGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/JQGrid/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/JQGrid/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/JQGrid/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/JQGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```